# Is there any kind of comics search engine by text

Tags: webapp-rec

The title is quite clear, however, let me detail a little.

I'm an avid reader of

- [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/)
- [Dilbert](http://www.dilbert.com/)
- [Abstruse Goose](http://abstrusegoose.com/)

All these comics have, of course, more or less nice images, but also text. A long time ago, I read [somewhere](http://the.taoofmac.com/space/blog/2008/03/11/2253) it would be great to index all those strips based upon their content.

So, is there any kind of image search engine allowing search based upon text recognized using some kind of OCR?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5940/is-there-a-peanuts-database-search-engine

Comment: It's quite harder with the comics, because usually they are using handwritten text. They have somehow include the text on their own. But all of these that you mentioned are popular and maybe some kind of collaboration from their side and the search engines part would be interesting. Give it a shot and ask xkcd or Dilbert directly if they have something planned.. :) It will be awesome if they could make it happen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [OhNo Robot](http://www.ohnorobot.com/). It's a croudsourced search engine that relies on people adding the text from the comics.

I don't know how up to date it is, but might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

BF Martin's [Dilbert Strip Finder](http://www.bfmartin.ca/finder)

I've received lots of good feedback when I've used it to find an appropriate image for the middle of a boring report.

Answer (score 0):

Pages showing strips on XKCD have a transcript that is hidden from human viewers but picked up by search engines. So you can search for XKCD cartoons by keyword using a search query like this on Google - [keyword -site:*.xkcd.com site:xkcd.com]

The first ***site*** operator negation in the query is to [exclude subdomains](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/how-do-i-restrict-google-search-site-operator-by-excluding-subdomains) (like forums.xkcd.com)