# How do I restrict Google search site operator by excluding subdomains?

Tags: google-search

Let's say I ran the following query in Google's web search:

```
site:"superuser.com" "windows 7"
```

This will return results on the blog.superuser.com subdomain.

How can I restrict results to only be from the superuser.com domain and not any other subdomain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will do the trick:

[ ["windows 7" site:superuser.com -site:*.superuser.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22windows%207%22%20site%3asuperuser.com%20-site%3a%2a.superuser.com) ]

> **This method has varying results and does not work for sites such as**
>
> - stackexchange.com
> - cnn.com
> - fox.com
> - internet.com

Comment: This works, until a new subdomain is added. Probably better to change it to `-site:*.superuser.com`.

Comment: Doesn't work for a domain like stackexchange.com - replace your example with **stackexchange.com** and you'll see tex.stackexchange.com and apple.stackexchange.com come up

Comment: This also does not work for: bbc.co.uk, cnn.com, fox.com, internet.com, cnet.com, etc

Comment: This does not work at all, it just *happens* to work for the domain in the question by chance. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19493/10579

Answer (score 8):

Rather than using the `site:` search operator try using `inurl:` instead along with the `+` operator. Seems to work pretty well for me.

`asd +[inurl:http://stackexchange.com]`

or in the case of this question:

`"windows 7" +[inurl:http://superuser.com]`

Note: Posting this answer in response to [this recent duplicate question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19493/googling-results-from-a-single-domain-and-excluding-its-subdomains#question)

Tests for other sites

- `newspulse +[inurl:http://cnn.com]`  no newspulse.cnn.com
- `The Latest Scripts from JavaScript Source +[inurl:http://internet.com]` no javascript.internet.com

Comment: This doesn't work for me, at least not from mobile.

Comment: @codingbadger, What's the point of the plus operator? (Isn't `+` operator gone since a long time ago...  http://searchengineland.com/google-sunsets-search-operator-98189 )

Answer (score 0):

Unsure about the other post (2011) but I've just tried and it works seamlessly:

- [blog site:superuser.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=blog+site:superuser.com+)
  [blog site:superuser.com -site:*.superuser.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=blog+site:superuser.com+-site:*.superuser.com)
- [english site:stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=english+site:stackexchange.com+)
  [english site:stackexchange.com -site:*.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=english+site:stackexchange.com+-site:*.stackexchange.com)
- [coupons site:cnn.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=coupons+site:cnn.com+)
  [coupons site:cnn.com -site:*.cnn.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=coupons+site:cnn.com+-site:*.cnn.com)
- [weather site:fox.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=weather+site:fox.com+)
  [weather site:fox.com -site:*.fox.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=weather+site:fox.com+-site:*.fox.com)
- [site:internet.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=+site:internet.com+) 
   [site:internet.com -site:*.internet.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=+site:internet.com+-site:*.internet.com)

Answer (score 0):

Add `inurl:www`

`site:"superuser.com" "windows 7" inurl:www`

It seems to work perfect for me!

Another option would be to use the - operator to exclude the individual subdomains manually.

Eg:
`site:"superuser.com" "windows 7" -inurl:subdomain`

Answer (score -1):

Another simple way to do that is to specify which subdomain you want to be cuted off from the final query, you can do as follows:

```
site:domain.com -subdomain -subdomain
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in several answers made prior to this one and does not add to those answers. As per the [Help Center on what answers are deleted](/help/deleted-answers), duplicates of other answers may be deleted.

Answer (score -3):

```
site:superuser.com -site:*.superuser.com "windows 7"
```

Comment: This seems to be identical to the solution in [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/17634), which apparently doesn't work.